# Foreign iframe in my site is unclickable

Tags: magento, iframe, xss

I have a Magento Webshop for plastic parts which can be custom configured by the user with the help of an iframe from a different domain. Unfortunately I am completely unable to click anything inside this frame.

Could this be a cross site scripting protection? I tried raising the z-index of the iframe to make sure it's the top most element in my design but I was still not able to click on anything. However if I use tab I can navigate to the elements inside the iframe.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

XSS is a vulnerability, so it is not related. Use Firefox, install the Web developer add on, and click the "display topographic information" in that toolbar. Should help you determine whats blocking the clicks. Also look for sandbox attributes on the iframe. Will block javascript.